# js headhesive & ajax

Tags: javascript, плагин

Как подружить плагин js headhesive с "ajax". Плагин создает копию части дом документа и потом получается что другие скрипты не могут работать. Надо как то встраиватся внутрь самого плагина или совсем его выпиливать? Есть еще какие-то варианты. И какой более предпочтительный?

Comment: Нужно больше информации

Comment: как плагин с ajax связан?

Comment: Я так понимаю это достаточно типичная проблема когда один плагин мешает работать другому. Допустим один из них отрабатывает по событию типа document ready как в случае с headhesive а другой плагин который срабатывает на событие onclick не может отработать т.к. до этого плагин отработавший раньше в моем случае headhesive изменил DOM документ и как я понимаю не имеет к нему доступа... По сути на этом месте может быть любой другой плагин...